firehose operation timed out LOG: ERROR: Only nop and sig tag can be recevied before authentication
qdl   --include . prog_ufs_firehose_sdm855_ddr.elf rawprogram0.xml rawprogram1.xml rawprogram2.xml rawprogram3.xml rawprogram4.xml rawprogram5.xml patch0.xml patch1.xml patch2.xml patch3.xml patch4.xml patch5.xml 
HELLO version: 0x2 compatible: 0x1 max_len: 1024 mode: 0
READ64 image: 13 offset: 0x0 length: 0x40
READ64 image: 13 offset: 0x40 length: 0x460
READ64 image: 13 offset: 0x1000 length: 0x1000
.
.
READ64 image: 13 offset: 0x2000 length: 0xd68
.
.
READ64 image: 13 offset: 0xad0a0 length: 0x1000
END OF IMAGE image: 13 status: 0
DONE status: 1
LOG: INFO: Binary build date: Jun 13 2019 @ 13:44:21
LOG: INFO: Binary build date: Jun 13 2019 @ 13:44:21
LOG: INFO: Chip serial num:
LOG: INFO: Supported Functions (15):
LOG: INFO: program
LOG: INFO: read
LOG: INFO: nop
LOG: INFO: patch
LOG: INFO: configure
LOG: INFO: setbootablestoragedrive
LOG: INFO: erase
LOG: INFO: power
LOG: INFO: firmwarewrite
LOG: INFO: getstorageinfo
LOG: INFO: benchmark
LOG: INFO: emmc
LOG: INFO: ufs
LOG: INFO: fixgpt
LOG: INFO: getsha256digest
LOG: INFO: End of supported functions 15

qdl: firehose operation timed out LOG: ERROR: Only nop and sig tag can
be recevied before authentication.

